# Statefulset - How automatically setting labels to pods after creation and restarting?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset

I have statefulset `mongo-replica`, It creates Two replica, I want to set a new label ( COMPANY ) foreach pod (replica) it's value should be the pod's name .e.g.:

```
in POD mongo-replica-0 -> COMPANY: mongo-replica-0
in POD mongo-replica-1 -> COMPANY: mongo-replica-1
```

So, Is there away to do it, `automatically` in Creating/Restarting pod ?

I know we can do it via `kubectl label`, but it manual

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing this, there is not such a dedicated tool for this purpose. There are two things that comes to my mind here:

- Use an `initContainer` for the Statefulset Pods that uses service
  account created upon it with appropriate permissions. `initContainer`
  will then run a command like `kubectl label pod $hostname company=$HOSTNAME"`

  This article shows how run [kubectl from within a
  pod](https://itnext.io/running-kubectl-commands-from-within-a-pod-b303e8176088) with image build, service account and roles creation.

- Creating some sort of bash script that will run in pod/job and automate this process for you:

```
 a=$(kubectl get pods -o jsonpath='{.items[*].[metadata.name](http://metadata.name/)}' -l app=$stsname) for n in $a ; do kubectl label pod $n company="$n" --overwrite ; done
```

- Create custom mutating webhook/controller that will modify those objects.

Here is good article that describes how to write basic [kubernetes mutating admission webhook](https://medium.com/ovni/writing-a-very-basic-kubernetes-mutating-admission-webhook-398dbbcb63ec#:%7E:text=Mutating%20admission%20webhooks%20allow%20you,etc.). Kubernetes official documentaion shares a very good section about [dynamic admission control](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/) that is worth checking out.